# Using Sharepoint as intranet, how much are user licenses

Tags: intranet, license

I'm trying to find out if I need licenses for all employees viewing a Sharepoint based intranet and if so, how much are those licenses?

Thanks,

Gill

Answer (score 0):

Yes all users need a license.

Are you online then you an Office365 subscription for all users. There are many to choose from.

Are you on prem, you ned a CAL for each user.